# Registration before checkout does not work

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout

When I want to register before checkout, nothing happen...

After filling the fields about billing (firstname, lastname, adress...), I click on "Continue" and it goes back to the cart page.

You can check the site here : http://bit.ly/MypZMT

Why and how to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Check the response you get from the ajax call when you click continue. A link to your website can help also.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is the url of the wbesite : http://bit.ly/MypZMT

Comment: You are getting an error when saving the billing address `500 Internal Server Error`. Check `var/log` for errors.

Comment: Logs were not enabled...
So I retried, and I got these errors :
Notice: Undefined variable: getDashboardUrl  in /default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 42
Notice: Undefined index: order  /default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml on line 81
Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_BLOWFISH - assumed 'MCRYPT_BLOWFISH'  in /lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 56
Notice: Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_MODE_ECB - assumed 'MCRYPT_MODE_ECB'  in /lib/Varien/Crypt/Mcrypt.php on line 60

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments I conclude that you are missing the `mcrypt` php extension.
Enable it on your server and everything should run smoothly.