# Checkout page redirects to cart page after filling billing address

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have a issue in checkout page. After filling up shipping address and hitting continue button, the site redirect to cart page without emptying the cart. When I inspecting the checkout page with Firebug, the below link is thrown `500 Internal Server Error`,

```
www.website.com/index.php/checkout/onepage/saveBilling/
```

I have followed some magentocommerce [links](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/261778/) to find out the issue, but no use.

What will be the issue? Any assistance will be helpful.

This is the error I am getting in error log:

```
2014-01-30T09:08:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(SoapClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-01-30T09:08:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(SoapClient.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
2014-01-30T09:08:44+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'SoapClient.php' for inclusion (include_path='/var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/app/code/local:/var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/app/code/community:/var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/app/code/core:/var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/lib:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')  in /var/www/vhosts/website.com/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93
```

Comment: Maybe this is your problem also: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/14126/146

Comment: @Marius Mcrypt is installed.

Comment: OK. Just trying to shoot in the dark. You should enable your log and check for possible errors in `var/log` and add the error message to the question.

Comment: @Marius I have updated the question. added errors from error log [system.log]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments I conclude that you don't have the soap php extension enabled.
This is not a problem normally for Magento because on the checkout it doesn't require SOAP for anything.
Either you have an extension that does something with SOAP when saving the billing address , maybe a shipping method that retrieves the shipping costs 'live' or the error messages logged in `system.log` come from somwehere else.
I suggest enabling the soap extension and trying again.

Comment: Its working now. I have installed `php-soap` in my server. Soap was the reason to that problem. Thanks you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out your log files. If they aren't enabled, you can enable them in admin palel: System->Configuration->(Advanced section)Developer->Log settings. Another option is to review the Apache/Nginx error logs.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-logs/

Check if this file SoapClient.php is placed in one of the directories that the autoloader knows about app/code/local, app/code/community, lib.